# Winload.exe missing or corrupt

Tags: windows-server-2008

I shut down my Windows Server 2008 machine, but upon restart I was presented with as screen stating that:

```
Windows has failed to start.  A recent hardware or software change might be the cause...

File:  \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Status:  0x000000f

Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt
```

It is a Dell PowerEdge T300 server running Windows Server 2008 64bit with only VMWare installed.

Comment: I'm confused. Is it a VM that's giving you this message? Does the box have VMware <something> or Windows Server 2008 on it?

Comment: Sorry.  It is not a VM server, it is the physical box which hosts VMware.  So actually all of my VMs are offline.  :(

Comment: Still confused. What VMware product are you using? What is actually installed on the box?

Comment: Forget that I mentioned VMware this has nothing to do with it.  I solved the issue, howevever, since I do not have enough "street cred" I cannot post my answer for another couple hours.   hmm.. Kind of perplexed as to how this legit question got 2 tics down?

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured this out with the help of this [website](http://www.technoish.com/microsoft/vista-problems/how-to-avoid-or-fix-winloadexe-corrupt-in-windows-vista/).

In summary, I used the Win2008 dvd to boot up and using the recovery tool was able to get to the command prompt.  Once there I ran the following commands:

C:> **bootrec.exe /fixmbr**

C:> **bootrec.exe /fixboot**

This did the trick and my server is alive again.